# Python iterator behaviour

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Given an arbitrary input string I'm meant to find the sum of all numbers in that string.
This obviously requires that i know the NEXT element in string while iterating through it...and make the decision whether its an integer. if the previous element was an integer also, the two elements form a new integer, all other characters are ignored and so on.

For instance  an input string

```
ab123r.t5689yhu8
```

should result in the sum of `123 + 5689 + 8 = 5820`.

All this is to be done without using regular expressions.

I have implemented an iterator in python, whose (next()) method  i think returns the next element, but passing the input string

```
acdre2345ty
```

I'm getting the following output

```
a
c
d
r
e
2
4
t
y
```

Some numbers 3 and 5 are missing...why is this? I need that the `next()` to work for me to be able to sift through an input string and do the calculations correctly

Better still, how should i implement the next method so that it yields the element to the immediate right during a given iteration?

Here is my code

```
class Inputiterator(object):
    '''
    a simple iterator to yield all elements from a given
    string successively from  a given input string
    '''
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        """
        check whether we've reached the end of the input
        string, if not continue returning the current value
        """
        if self.index == len(self.data)-1:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index + 1
        return self.data[self.index]

# Create a method to get the input from the user
# simply return a string

def get_input_as_string():
    input=raw_input("Please enter an arbitrary string of numbers")
    return input

def sort_by_type():
    maininput= Inputiterator(get_input_as_string())
    list=[]
    s=""
    for char in maininput:
        if str(char).isalpha():
            print ""+ str(char)
        elif str(char).isdigit() and str(maininput.next()).isdigit():
            print ""+ str(char)

sort_by_type()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I first deleted this answer as there are much better solutions for your problem in this thread, but as you are directly asking how to use the next method to get your code working I have recovered it, in case you find it useful.

Try this (I mocked the iterator for convenience):

```
def sort_by_type():
    maininput = iter("acdre2345ty")

    for char in maininput:
        if char.isalpha():
            print char
        elif char.isdigit():
            number = char
            while True:
                # try/except could take care of the StopIteration exception 
                # when a digit is last in the string
                #
                # try:
                #    char = maininput.next()
                # except StopIteration:
                #    char = ""
                #
                # however using next(iterator, default) is much better:
                #
                char = next(maininput, "")

                if char.isdigit():
                    number += char
                else:
                    break
            print number
            print char
```

if produces:

```
a
c
d
r
e
2345
t
y
```

Comment: Try it with `maininput = iter("acdre2345ty2390")`

Comment: `char = next(maininput, '')` instead `char = maininput.next()` will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I did it the long way. I prefer your solution.

Comment: +1 I think this answer is the closest to what OP was looking for, although more elegant solutions allready provided.

Comment: Thanks!! i was actually looking for solution of this type.

Answer (score 9):

Python strings are already iterable, no need to create you own iterator.

What you want is thus simply achieved without iterators:

```
s = "acdre2345ty2390"

total = 0
num = 0

for c in s:
    if c.isdigit():
        num = num * 10 + int(c)
    else:
        total += num
        num = 0

total += num
```

Which results in:

```
>>> print total
4735
```

Comment: extremely elegant solution..thank you!!!. This is why i decided to begin programming in python.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'ab123r#t5689yhu8'
tot = 0
for k, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit):
    if k:
        tot += int(''.join(g))
```

Or in one line *(as suggested in the comments down below)*:

```
tot = sum((int(''.join(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit) if k)
```

Comment: Mmmh... couldn't resist: `tot = sum((int(''.join(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, lambda c: c.isdigit()) if k))`

Comment: There's actually no need for the lambda here: `tot = sum((int(''.join(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit) if k)`

Answer (score 1):

For entertainment purposes only (I couldn't resist, 49 chars):

```
eval(''.join([['+0+',x][x.isdigit()]for x in s]))
```

Comment: hehe: `import re ; eval(re.sub('\D+','+',s))`, 37! But the OP said he doesn't want regexes :-(